# In a formula of distinct count algorithm, what ^ notation mean?

Tags: math, count, statistics, distinct

In the first line, there is ^ notation between (epsilon*d/2^r) and (t = r).

What does ^ mean?

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because you should ask it on math.stackexchange.com, rather than here.

Comment: it is a formula for distinct counting and it is a boundary of software development. But it may be more suitable for math.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "^" symbol in this context means "and" (which may be known as `&&` in C++ or C#).